# Presenting a ViewController over another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've got a pretty lengthy question today, as it takes some amount of explaining. Let's start with an example.

---

### Example

Let's say I have three view controllers:

1. FullSizeViewController
2. FirstViewController
3. SecondViewController

FullSizeViewController, as the name states, is intended to take the space of the whole screen. FirstViewController and SecondViewController, on the other hand, should only take up about 3/4 of the height of the screen. Here's a few pictures to illustrate.

[image: FullSizeViewController]

Here we have FullSizeViewController. Nothing special, just two buttons - "First" & "Second". If you haven't already caught on by now, those two buttons should toggle each of the respective view controllers, as shown below.

[image: FirstViewContoller]

---

### The Issue

I'm having the main issues with this? How would I be able to

1. Animate the view controllers from the bottom
2. Change the size of the two smaller view controllers
3. Still allow interaction with the FullSizeViewController even as a small view controller is open on top of its main content, but not the two toggle buttons?

---

### What I've Tried

Since I'm not too sure how to do this, I haven't tried all that much, but I have tried one thing.

In the IBAction connected to the "First" button:

```
let firstVC: FirstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController")! as FirstViewController
        self.presentViewController(firstVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In viewDidLoad of FirstViewController:

```
self.view.frame.size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 68)
```

---

tl;dr How can I achieve [this](http://gyazo.com/a84d0cd66ed3ec9f1b9dd6e0294383dc)?

Comment: There's a million different ways to do this, and none of the methods can be explained really fully explained within the character limit on answers--this question is way, way too broad.  Break your problem down into smaller subsets of problems and tackle them one at a time.  Please note--this doesn't mean turn this single question into 4 or 5 different questions.  This means put some effort into making some actual headway.  This isn't *too* difficult, but it's also not the simplest of UI programming...

Comment: Your tl;dr should be at the top… people that don't care aren't going to make it down that far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your full-size *VC* should be a `custom container view controller`. When you want one of the other controllers to come on screen, you instantiate it, size it how you want, add it as a `*child view controller*`, and use `animateWithDuration` to change its frame from off the bottom of the screen to where you want it to end up.

You shouldn't use `presentViewController` since that gives you a modal *VC* that takes over the whole screen. You should read the document called "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" if you haven't already.